# If $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] was 404 Page Not Found

Tags: php, apache

In PHP is there any way to catch a 404 not found?

If a user ends up on a 404, I want them to be redirected to a known page, but to display something different if it is due to a 404 error.

Something like

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 404){
    echo("You've been redirected!");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not redirect on errors unless it's a permanent one such as a page moved to a different url. For real errors redirecting is extremely annoying since you e.g. cannot easily correct a typo in the URL or hit F5.

Comment: I was thinking that if the page is not found, set a flag saying it resulted in a 404, and then redirect to a search page saying something like 'we could not find + query' but try searching etc. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, how about `mod_rewrite`, or other methods of loading another page without changing the address bar, e.g., `require`.

Comment: Redirecting so a seach page is annoying, but displaying the search page or any other page *without* redirecting is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is only given the path to the page that referred you to the current page, it can't retrieve the status code for that page.

You shouldn't need to *redirect* the page when the page specified doesn't exist. In Apache you can specify the ErrorDocument to be a PHP file, just append a query string to the file such as `ErrorDocument /index.php?error=404` so that your PHP file knows the page being requested doesn't exist. This way you can display the error straight to the user on the same page and the URL isn't lost. You don't need session or server variables, just a `$_GET['error']` to check if there is an error code provided to the page.

Or, you can specify a pre-built document that is just a 404 error page, such as an `ErrorDocument my404error.html`, which will be displayed without any server-side processing for the page which is not found.

Comment: Perfect! It really didn't cross my mind to use PHP GET. Thanks v much!

Comment: And then you may use a `header("Location: $loc");` in your 404 error doc to redirect to the page you like.

Comment: Just tried what you said, htaccess doesnt pass the url, for example www.example.com/notexists, with a htaccess redirect loads the right page but the url remains www.example.com/notexists

Comment: @Cristian: The URL should remain the same. That way search spiders, etc know *that URL* produces the 404 not found. Otherwise they will think that page redirects to another page which does not exist.